# Ocultar botão com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como faço para esconder um botão que só o admin logado possa ver. Tenho uma regra de negocio com a mesma interface, mas tem um botão específico que só o admin tem acesso. Como fazer isso com `jquery`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a unção hide do Jquery.
Veja abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(true /* sua validação se é admin aqui*/){
    $('#btn-salvar').hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button  id="btn-visualizar"> Visualizar </button>
<button id="btn-salvar"> Salvar </button>
```

Comment: Valeu meu amigo obrigado

Comment: Esconder um botão que apenas um administrador pode usar no frontend é uma falha de segurança, este botão deve ser escondido no servidor. Senão qualquer usuário que saiba inspecionar elemento pode mostrar o botão e clicar nele, mesmo não sendo administrador.

Comment: Sim valeu pela ajuda estou fazendo teste sabe para ver como faço pra esconder o botão, valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está recebendo a informação através da sua **linguagem servidora**, sabendo isso, recomendo que utilize um próprio **if**, verificando se esse seu usuário é um administrador, caso ele não for, você simplesmente não faz nada.

Por exemplo em PHP:

```
<?php if(usuario.permissao == "administrador"){ ?>
<button></button>
<?php } ?>
```

Se caso essa informação estiver vindo através de uma requisição de JavaScript, por exemplo, Ajax. Você pode fazer a mesma verificação no JS, porém você deve capturar o elemento e oculta-lo.

Exemplo:

```
if(data.permissao !== "administrador"){
var btn = $("#idDoSeuBtn");
btn.hide();
}
```

Espero ter lhe ajudado, se ainda houver dúvidas, por favor me comunica como chega suas informações para ser efetuado as correções.